# Is there an alternative to displaying a large amount of text using strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, tableview, user-experience

My android app involves a readable online brochure containing multiple tables. Due to which it has over 5000 string values saved in the strings.xml file that is referenced in the content_main.xml

I have 2 questions with respect to the above statement:

1. Is this the best way approach to display such large quantity of
   hard-coded data or does an alternative exist?
2. Can I import an excel sheet and populate the xml layout with it while still being able to access the xml attributes for that layout?

PS: Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can have several string.xml files with different names.

Comment: no i think she have only one string.xml file and it that file have 5000 values .....

Comment: Yes, this is the best and recommended approach to store large amount of hard-coded data in strings.xml :)